# How to Create 32 bit apk in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I  have a device  it only supports 32bit   so now google  change   the   policy of   apk   it defaults   64bit   export so  please tell  me how I can  create   the 32-bit apk

Comment: it supports both 32bit and 64bit APK.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have native (NDK C++) code in your app and if you only write Java/kotlin code in your app then you don't need to do anything for it otherwise add this

`ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'`

in defaultConfig module build.gradle file to support for 32 as well as 64 bit OS system

Comment: This setting needs to be inside the defaultConfig section inside the android section.